# How to catch two different types of bad input

Tags: python, exception

I am writing a code in python 3 where I need to have two different strings output depending on what the input was. 
They are both ValueErrors.

```
try:
    number = False
    while number == False:
        chooseword = int(input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: "))

except ValueError: #empty input
    print("Empty input!")
except ValueError: #non-integer, non-empty input
    print("Input must be an integer!")
else: #do stuff
```

I have tried the approach from this question, but I only ever get one of the printed messages.
[How to catch empty user input using a try and except in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579997/how-to-catch-empty-user-input-using-a-try-and-except-in-python)

I have also tried to ignore a ValueError from one of the two choices by using a while loop and trying to catch the other choice with a try except block:

```
empty = True
while empty == True:
    chooseword = int(input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in   the list: "))
    if chooseword = "":
        empty = True
```

Comment: `if chooseword = "":` is a syntax error (single `=`, which is illegal in `if` statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're catching `ValueError`, the first `except` will always catch it. In fact, if you look at the `ValueError` `int()` raises, it's the same in both cases:

```
>>> int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> int('1.2')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'
```

If you want to catch the empty case specially, just look at the exception:

```
try:
  word = input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: ")
  word = int(word)
except ValueError as e:
  if not word:
    print("Empty!")
  else:
    print("Invalid!")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking around forever for something that would work, and I tried this but I missed having the int(word) in a different step from the input!

Answer (score 1):

Split the two error conditions so that each is handled separately:

```
number = None
while number is None:
    chooseword = input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: ")
    if not chooseword.strip():
        print("Empty input!")
    else:
        try:
            number = int(chooseword)
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer!")
```

In this case, `chooseword.strip()` will remove any whitespace characters from the input, so that empty or all-space inputs are handled as zero-length strings. If input *is* provided, the `try`/`except` block will catch any non-integer values.

Answer (score 0):

as value error is explained by others, you can also do the same by this method

```
while True:
    answer = input('Enter a number: ')
    if isinstance(answer,int) and answer in range(0,10):
        do_what_you want()
        break
    else:
        print "wrong Input"
        continue

print answer
```

`instance` method will check for the input is int or not, isinstance will return True if its int else False. answer in range will return if a is in between 0-9 else return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can reform python input function with this way:

Please define a new function like

```
def Input(Message):
```

Set a initial value like

```
Value = None
```

Until the entered value is not a number, try to get a number

```
while Value == None or Value.isdigit() == False:
```

Control I/O errors and so on

```
try:
    Value = str(input(Message)).strip()
except InputError:
    Value = None
```

At last, your can return your value that it's can be None or a true value.